# Load file selected in html page to pandas

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask

I am trying to automate the Winross(market research tool) tables syntax to generate Open-end tables. I need to use two excel files for this for which I am planning to use Pandas. I am not sure how to load the excel files into pandas which are selected in HTML using input type = "file".

Adding both HTML and python codes below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>OE Tables</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form class="" action="getfile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h1>OE Tables Generator</h1>
            <h3>Select OE data:</h3>
            <input type="file" name="myfile" value=""><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Upload OE File"><br><br>

            <h3>Select Code-frame:</h3>
            <input type="file" name="myfile" value=""><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Upload Code-frame"><br <br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/getfile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getfile():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        excel_file = request.files['myfile']
        oedata = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
        return oedata.head()

    else:
        result = request.args.get['myfile']
    return result
```

Currently getting a page with below error:
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: shouldnt be there app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='') and `   return app.render_template("index.html")` ? just fast thoughts

Comment: `pd.read_excel(excel_file.stream)`, judging from https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/datastructures/#others ?